Uusing REGEX to make ip in URL get a problem with router problem
I want to create a root localhost:3000/ip/{any IPv4 possible}
that's my index.ts (router file looks like)
import {createRouter, createWebHistory} from 'vue-router';
import IPView from "../views/IPView.vue";
import ErrorView from '../views/ErrorView.vue';
const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes: [{
        path: '/ip/:ip(\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.)',
        name: 'IPView',
        component: IPView,
        beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
            const ipRegex = /^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$/;
            if (ipRegex.test(to.params.ip as string)) {
                next();
            } else {
                next({
                    name: 'error'
                });
            }
        }
    }, {
        path: '/:pathMatch(.*)*',
        name: 'error',
        component: ErrorView
    }]
});

export default router;

IPView.vue:
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>IP View</h1>
    <p v-if="isValidIP">IP Address: {{ ip }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { useRoute, useRouter } from 'vue-router';
import { onMounted, ref } from 'vue';
</script>

When accessing localhost:3000/ip/34.7.8.3 I get the error (This localhost page can’t be found. HTTP ERROR 404 ) but when localhost:3000/ip/54jjk45 I get the 404 ErrorView page.
What am I doing wrong?

Please can you confirm that my understanding here is correct: the error for localhost:3000/ip/34.7.8.3 comes from the webserver (and the request never reaches your app), but the error from localhost:3000/ip/54jjk45 comes from your app?

Yes, your understanding is correct. @spender

What causes the problems are the dots in the url.

So, for an SPA, it is necessary for the server to redirect requests on arbitrary paths back to the application root. So that other media can still be retrieved by path, there must be some way to differentiate virtual routes from real routes. One cheap way of doing this is to assume that a . in the final segment of the url is for the purposes of a file-extension. This is assumed, therefore, to be a real resource on the webserver, and the rewrite to root is not applied by the webserver. Easiest fix? pass it in on a query string.

Even after creating a 1.1.1.1.vue page and a /1.1.1.1 URL, I still encounter the same issue. However, when I rename the virtual URL to just /1, I can access the 1.1.1.1.vue page. This proves that handling dots in URLs with vue-router is challenging.
